# In what city is this bus (tram?) located?

Tags: public-transport, identify-this

[image]

Curious to know where this picture is taken.

Comment: I've answered, but curious to know why you're asking?  And where's the rest of the stock picture?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That looks a lot like a [Transtech Artic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artic_(tram)) in the distinctive green-and-mustard colors of **Helsinki, Finland**:

[image]
*([courtesy Alex Hallberg, Wikimedia Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artic_(tram)#/media/File:Artic_(tram)_in_Helsinki.jpg))*